# Reflect the Option Values in HTML from google sheet using Google Apps Script and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a web application scheduler which selects the date and time. What I'm hoping for is, after a date has been selected, it will run a code which will check the existing data in the Google Sheet and check if the data exists 3 times then if exist the limit, it will look for the date on another sheet and reflect the row of data as select option in the html.

As of now, I have only the code for `JavaScript` which will call a function and access the google sheet in the `Google Apps Script`.

for JavaScript:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("subDate").addEventListener("change",setTime);

function setTime(){
var checkVal = document.getElementById("subTime").value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).timeCheck()
}

</script>
```

and Google Apps Script code to check the limit of the values in the google sheet.

for Google Apps Script:

```
function timeCheck(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");  
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 7, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();


  var CheckLimitReached = function (V)
  {
    var records= {};
    V.forEach(function (x) { records[x] = (records[x] || 0) + 1; });
    var limit_reached = Object.keys(records).filter(function (R) {
      return records[R] >= 3;});
    return limit_reached;

  };
   var dataDisable = CheckLimitReached(data);
   Logger.log(dataDisable);


  //return dateDisable;

}
```

this will be the Log Output:

```
[19-08-22 02:18:10:132 PDT] [Wed Aug 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT),8:00 AM]
```

here is also the link for the google sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lEfzjG1zzJVPMN8r-OpeZm6q9_IqSwk9DNCEY-q7ozY/edit?usp=sharing

I'm still working on a code to get the date value and time value separately in `var dataDisable` of the google script so that I can use it as match value in the sheet `Time_Select`. Because the value is treated as one value in an array as you can see in the Log Output.

I'm also trying to change the option value of the time. For example, if in `Test_Data` sheet the date August 28, 2019 and 8:00 AM exist 3 times. I will look for the August 28, 2019 in the 1st row of `Time_Select` sheet and then change the value of "8:00AM" to "Not Available" and then if some user select the "August 28, 2019" date in the web app, the option values which will be reflected would be:

```
Not Available
9:00 AM
10:00 AM
11:00 AM
12:00 NN
```

Thank you in advance for the help. I'm really new in programming so I am still working on it. I also apologize if the explanation is not so clear. I am willing to answer all questions regarding the issue so I can make it clearer. Please bear with me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

### To your first question:

Provided, `var dataDisabled` is an array containing several objects with of type `date`, you can separate the day and time as following:

```
var day=[];
var time=[];
for(var k=0;k<dataDisabled.length;k++)
 { 
  //please adapt the time zone and date formatting to your needs
day[k]=Utilities.formatDate(dataDisabled[k], 'GMT+2' , "MMMM dd,  YYYY");
time[k]= Utilities.formatDate(dataDisabled[k], 'GMT+2' ,' hh:mm a');
 }
```

I formatted the day and time according to the format in your spreadsheet, please consult all available format options [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/formatDate).

### To your second question:

A useful method for finding dates and times from `Test-Data` in `Time-Select` is `indexOf()`:

```
function notAvailable() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Test_Data");  
  var ts= ss.getSheetByName("Time_Select");  
  var data = ws.getRange(2, 7, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();
  var dataTimeSelect= ts.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 4).getValues();
  var arrayTimeSelect=[];
  for(var k=0;k<dataTimeSelect[0].length;k++){
     arrayTimeSelect.push(Utilities.formatDate(dataTimeSelect[0][k], 'GMT+2' , "MMMM dd,  YYYY")) 
    }
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var column=arrayTimeSelect.indexOf(Utilities.formatDate(data[i][0], 'GMT+2' , "MMMM dd,  YYYY"));
    for(var j=0;j<dataTimeSelect.length;j++){
      if(column!=-1){
        if(dataTimeSelect[j][column]==data[i][1]){
          ts.getRange(j+1, column+1).setValue('Not Available')
         }
      }
    }             
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your first solution, I changed the timezone to GMT+8. I received `"Missing ; before statement."` error. Upon searching, the solution was to remove the `var` in the `var day[k]=Utilities.formatDate(dataDisable[k], 'GMT+2' , "MMMM dd,  YYYY");` and `Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string).` error was received. Still looking for a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string) means that the content of `dataDisabled` are strings and not dates. I am not sure where you are getting the content from, but you have make sure that you parse a date object to `Utilities.formatDate()`. You can convert dateStrings to dates with new Date(dateString) https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp, provided that the dateString follows an accepted format: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: Since my output is `[Wed Aug 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (HKT),8:00 AM]` is it possible to separate the string date to the time like `[August 28, 2019, 8:00AM]`? I tried to make a variable `var dataTest = new Date(dataDisable);` and upon logging it the result was `Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 GMT+08:00 1970`. Im still trying to search how.

Comment: if you are happy to continue working with strings, you can use  str.split with RegExp: https://javascript.info/regexp-methods#str-replace-str-reg-str-func

Comment: are there other solution? Do I need to return it in the javascript or is it working in google script?

Comment: If the values in your range 'data' are valid date objects, you can use the solution in my answer.

Comment: So my problem now is how to convert it to date object. 

Comment: If you are retrieving data from a spreadsheet - the values should be automatically recognized as dates provided they are entered in an accepted format (see above)

Comment: Is it the same if the data comes from a date picker then send to the google sheet?